# Only thread handling io_service is waiting even though async I/O operations are pending

Tags: linux, multithreading, boost-asio

Boost's ASIO dispatcher seems to have a serious problem, and I can't seem to find a workaround. The symptom is that the only thread waiting to dispatch is left in `pthread_cond_wait` feven though there are I/O operations pending that require it to block in `epoll_wait`.

I can most easily replicate this issue by having one thread call `poll_one` in a loop until it returns zero. This can leave the thread calling `run` stuck in `pthread_cond_wait` while the thread calling `poll_one` breaks out of the loop. Presumably, the io_service is expecting that thread to return to block in `epoll_wait`, but it's under no obligation to do so and that expectation seems fatal.

Is there a requirement that threads be statically associated with `io_service`s?

Here's an example showing the deadlock. This is the only thread handling this io_service because the others have moved on. There are definitely socket operations pending:

```
#0 pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1 boost::asio::detail::posix_event::wait<boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock<boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex> > (...) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/posix_event.hpp:80
#2 boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::do_run_one (...) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp:405
#3 boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run (...) at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp:146
```

I believe the bug is as follows: If a thread servicing an I/O queue is the thread that's blocking on the I/O socket readiness check and it calls to a dispatch function, if there are any other threads blocked on the io service, it must signal. It currently only signals if there are handlers ready to run at that time. But that leaves no thread checking for socket readiness.

Comment: what's the return code from run_one()?

Comment: if it returns 1 that is normal, only when it returns 0 does the io_service need to be reset. It doesn't sound like you're doing anything incorrectly, can you post a sscce?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Are you sure the pthread_cond_timedwait call is from asio? I'm having some trouble seeing that in the code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz OK. Do you have one or multiple io_service instances?

Comment: @janm: In all the code? Tons of them. Many different portions of the code have their own io_service instances. This issue, however, seems to only relate to the one that has threads that can leave it to go do other things, leaving no thread left checking for socket readiness. (See updates.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz OK. Obvious question: Are the sockets with pending IO associated with the io_service instance blocked in pthread_cond_wait?

Comment: @janm: Yes. There are TCP listening sockets always associated with that io_service with `async_accept` pending. The symptom for our code is that those sockets stop accepting connections. Removing the thread migration resolves the issue.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Could well be a genuine bug; I don't have time to go through the asio code and check it out now. I haven't seen this problem, but I target FreeBSD, Windows and OSX, not Linux. And don't do thread migration like you. Will have a look later on.

Comment: if you suspect a bug in asio, update your question with your operating system and boost version.

Comment: @SamMiller: OS is above, Linux. The trace above is with Boost 1.50.

Comment: Eep. If that's not a bug then the design is just *horribly* broken.

Comment: @janm: Thanks, I appreciate it. This can affect you even if you don't do thread migration. Imagine if you have one handler that can take a very long time. So you make sure you have two threads calling into the dispatch loop. If you wind up with one thread doing the handler that takes a long time and the other blocked on the event, you're dead.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I agree, I don't think thread migration is the issue. I have been using boost.asio for a long time and it certainly is not horribly broken but bugs do happen.

Comment: @janm: I initially thought it was much bigger than it is. It's starting to look like a much subtler issue. (And if you read what Nik said, he carefully chose to put an "if" in there. He's right, if this isn't a bug, the design is badly broken. But it seems it *is* just a bug and the design is fine.)

Comment: For clarification, thread A loops calling `poll_one()` and returns 0, then thread B that is in `run()` remains blocked indefinitely without servicing the reactor?  I only briefly examined the code, so could use a second set of eyes, but looks like a bug to me.  If thread A runs reactor in `do_poll_one()`, `op_queue` is empty, then thread B becomes `first_idle_thread_`.  If no reactor operation is ready, then thread A returns `0`.  Thread A needs to invoke `wake_one_idle_thread_and_unlock(lock)` before returning `0`, causing thread B to wake up, re-enter `do_run_one()`, and service reactor.

Comment: @TannerSansbury: I believe that is correct. I am 100% sure that one thread is in `run` and one calls `poll_one` (or `poll`, no difference) and I wind up with the thread in `run` blocked in `pthread_cond_wait` and the other thread returns. Boom. Looking at the code, I believe the bug is that the signal only happens if there's work to do *now*. But if the thread was the one blocked in the reactor, it must signal whether or not there's work to do now to ensure some thread checks for socket readiness.

Comment: Submitted [bug and fix](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8354).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug.  I have been able to duplicate it by adding a delay into the non-critical section of `task_io_service::do_poll_one`.  Here is a snippet of the modified `task_io_service::do_poll_one()` in [`booost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp`](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp).  The only line added is the sleep.

```cpp
std::size_t task_io_service::do_poll_one(mutex::scoped_lock& lock,
    task_io_service::thread_info& this_thread,
    const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
  if (stopped_)
    return 0;

  operation* o = op_queue_.front();
  if (o == &task_operation_)
  {
    op_queue_.pop();
    lock.unlock();

    {
      task_cleanup c = { this, &lock, &this_thread };
      (void)c;

      // Run the task. May throw an exception. Only block if the operation
      // queue is empty and we're not polling, otherwise we want to return
      // as soon as possible.
      task_->run(false, this_thread.private_op_queue);
      boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(3));
    }

    o = op_queue_.front();
    if (o == &task_operation_)
      return 0;
  }

...
```

My test driver is fairly basic:

- An asynchronous work loop via a timer that will print "." every 3 seconds.
- Spawn off a single thread that will poll the `io_service`.
- Delay to allow the new thread time to poll `io_service`, and have main call `io_service::run()` while the poll thread sleeps in `task_io_service::do_poll_one()`.

Test code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::steady_timer timer(io_service);

void arm_timer()
{
  std::cout << ".";
  std::cout.flush();
  timer.expires_from_now(boost::chrono::seconds(3));
  timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&arm_timer));
}

int main()
{
  // Add asynchronous work loop.
  arm_timer();

  // Spawn poll thread.
  boost::thread poll_thread(
    boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::poll, boost::ref(io_service)));

  // Give time for poll thread service reactor.
  boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));

  io_service.run();
}
```

And the debug:

```
[twsansbury@localhost bug]$ gdb a.out 
...
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/twsansbury/dev/bug/a.out 

[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
.[New Thread 0xb7feeb90 (LWP 31892)]
[Thread 0xb7feeb90 (LWP 31892) exited]
```

At this point, the `arm_timer()` has printed "." once (when it was intially armed).  The poll thread serviced the reactor in a non-blocking manner, and slept for 3 seconds while `op_queue_` was empty (`task_operation_` will be added back to the `op_queue_` when `task_cleanup c` exits scope).  While the `op_queue_` was empty, the main thread calls `io_service::run()`, sees the `op_queue_` is empty, and makes itself the `first_idle_thread_`, where it waits on its `wakeup_event`.  The poll thread finishes sleeping, and returns `0`, leaving the main thread waiting on `wakeup_event`.

After waiting 10~ seconds, plenty of time for the `arm_timer()` to be ready, I interrupt the debugger:

```
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00919402 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00919402 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x0081bbc5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00763b3d in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x08059dc2 in void boost::asio::detail::posix_event::wait >(boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock&) ()
#4  0x0805a009 in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock&, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_thread_info&, boost::system::error_code const&) ()
#5  0x0805a11c in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run(boost::system::error_code&) ()
#6  0x0805a1e2 in boost::asio::io_service::run() ()
#7  0x0804db78 in main ()
```

---

The side-by-side timeline is as follows:

```
          poll thread                  |          main thread
---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------
  lock()                               | 
  do_poll_one()                        |                          
  |-- pop task_operation_ from         |
  |   queue_op_                        |
  |-- unlock()                         |  lock()
  |-- create task_cleanup              |  do_run_one()
  |-- service reactor (non-block)      |  `-- queue_op_ is empty
  |-- ~task_cleanup()                  |      |-- set thread as idle
  |   |-- lock()                       |      `-- unlock()
  |   `-- queue_op_.push(              |
  |       task_operation_)             |
  `-- task_operation_ is               | 
      queue_op_.front()                |
      `-- return 0                     |  // still waiting on wakeup_event
  unlock()                             |
```

---

As best as I could tell, there are no side effects by patching:

```cpp
if (o == &task_operation_)
  return 0;
```

to:

```cpp
if (o == &task_operation_)
{
  if (!one_thread_)
    wake_one_thread_and_unlock(lock);
  return 0;
}
```

Regardless, I have submitted a [bug and fix](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8354).  Consider keeping an eye on the ticket for an official response.